# Flask debug not respond on requests when start from visual studio code

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, flask, visual-studio-code

I have flask app and visual studio code as ide.
When i start debug from python2.7 environment with command
`python manager.py runserver -h 0.0.0.0 -p 9101` it will start properly and can responce on requests. But I cannot debug it with breakpoint in files

[image]

i add in `launch.json` next config

```
        {
        "name": "Flask",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/manage.py",
        "env": {
            "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceRoot}/manage.py",
        },
        "args": [
            "runserver",
            "-h",
            "0.0.0.0",
            "-p",
            "9101",
        ],
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
```

and try launch debug. in console i get next text

[image]

and its not respond on requests. if send request, it will be wait answer infinity time (its not return 404 or another error).

What need to do for debug?

i tried add params

```
"--no-debugger",
"--no-reload"
```

but its not launch with error

[image]

if i change runserver to run its get next error

[image]

Comment: I would try with the default Flask debug configuration as your settings above have deviated quite a bit and honestly look like the Django debug configuration.

Comment: its lookslike only for renserve? i tryed set it to run, its raise error

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you wrote.

Comment: add picture with error if i run it with simple run (not runserver) parameter

Comment: It might be because `manage.py` is not part of Flask but some third-party thing. I'm not sure where you got it from, but it may be breaking the debugger. You will need to file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd with a link to a repo with code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok, i try add issue to repo. It's not my project, i only try work with it and debug.